# Matplolib, put text in front of graphs

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have created some subplots using matplotlib librairies (pyplot and gridspec). I am trying to put some text in front of the graphs, but sometimes they are located below, in the background so I can't see them.
I don't know if I should used plt.text or annonate or rather use methods of sublplots?

Answer (score 0):

If you change the command window to white you should be able to see the text. If you are using the command `%matplotlib inline`, together with a black command window, the text will not always be visible.